# Проблема с модулем geoip

Tags: php, dle

Не могу понять, что не так, у меня dle 9.3, ставил модуль онлайн. Пишет вот такую ошибку

> `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare  geoip_country_code_by_name() in /home/sergey1/test/engine/classes/geoip/geoip.inc on line 346`

Вот сам файл: http://rghost.ru/13295701. Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 2):

geoip_country_code_by_name() функция уже определена, и переопределить её не получиться, т.к. php не поддерживает перегрузку функций.

Но если бы вы воспользовались google, то смогли бы сами найти решение, попробуйте обернуть функцию в

```
if (!function_exists('<function name>')) {
//функция
}
```

Comment: Не помогло,может полностью распишешь,я просто только начинающий в дле.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам также поможет следующий совет: замените все `include` на [`include_once`](http://php.su/functions/?include_once) (тут надо быть аккуратным, вероятно может использоваться результат возвращаемый include, если использует, то заменять не надо) и `requare` на [`requare_once`](http://php.su/functions/?require_once), это позволит избежать многократного подключения одних и тех же скриптов и как следствие, ВОЗМОЖНО, не даст переопределить функцию. Если это не многократное подключение одного и тогоже скрипта, скорее всего Вам придется все-таки вникать в код, чтобы исправить ошибку.

P.S. [[@uvlad](/users/2217/uvlad)](/users/2217/uvlad) предложил обернуть объявление функции в if, чтобы избежать попытки объявить итак существующую функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вы подключаете один и тот же файл дважды. Пересмотрите логику работы программы так, чтобы этого не происходило.
Если это сложно, то два варианта вам уже предложили. Я же предложу третий - измените geoip.inc таким вот образом:

```
if(!defined('GEO_IP_INC'))
{
    define('GEO_IP_INC', 1);
    //код geoip.inc
}
```

Результат - тот же, что и при использовании include/require_once;

Answer (score 0):

Похоже что у вас включен php модуль geoip. Выключите модуль либо же разделие код:
if(extension_loaded('geoip')) {
...
} else {
...
}